# When are the symbols ⊕ and ♁ used to designate Earth?

Tags: symbols

In astronomy I usually see Earth designated with a circled plus or cross. NASA [says](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/680/solar-system-symbols/) this is the Earth's astronomical symbol. Wikipedia tends to use it, for example designating the Earth–Moon distance by $\Delta_{\oplus L}$. But Wikipedia also [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_symbol) that the globus cruciger ♁ is used to symbolize Earth.

Does the latter find any usage in astronomy?

(The actual Unicode code point for the circled plus Earth symbol is U+1F728 but this does not render for me, so I used the graphically similar U+2295 instead.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I don't know how common the globus cruciger is, but it is used at least here for the electron neutrino pp flux at Earth: [NEUTRINO 2006: Proceedings of the XXIIth International Conference on Neutrino Physics and Astrophysics](https://lss.fnal.gov/conf/C0606131/Neutrino06-Proceedings.pdf).

Comment: First occurrence seems to be in the abstract on p 92.